# Can we start a Magento2 chatroom on Discord?

Tags: discussion, magento2

I currently chat on the Discord for React JS[1] and it's quite amazing. I think the Magento developer community is of similar size, activeness, and if we restrict it to Magento2, the code also resembles React.

I consider myself a decent Magento developer and I am having the absolute worst time ever beginning with Magento2. Documentation is fragmented, most of the content is duplicate, and with the codebase in constant flux, solutions become out of date very quickly.

1: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/19/reactiflux-is-moving-to-discord.html

Answer (score 5):

Sure, even if iam not sure who you meant with "we". For a community with this size its ok to have multiple different chat/communication channels.

To list some of them: irc, reddit, magechat( slack), gitter. Even stackexchange has an own chat system

Some of them have dedicated mage2 channels, others not (yet).

I did not look yet how discord works, but i expect you may need someone who is willing to administrate/moderate it. The best person for this is probably yourself, if noone else wants to volunteer.

Answer (score 0):

I'de be down for that, Discord has very nice code embed with backticks and specifying language. But it needs to be a chat where people can actually help. Many questions I've asked in their other chats just go ignored T_T.

Comment: The Discord of OpenMage (a Magento1 Fork) is quite active and has many people who have experience with Magento https://discord.gg/CxBYKue

Comment: Magento 1 is basically dead (End of life), I'm migrating our 2nd to last website away from it now.

I do see that there is a Magento 2 channel in the OpenMage discord, having just joined not sure how active it is.

Thanks I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

you all guys can join Magento 2 community in Discord here https://discord.gg/ZpHfkXnK